# How to get cookies value on another page with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have called one PHP page inside an iframe

I have stored some values in cookies. I want to read those cookies values from that page to other page.

I used jQuery to read the cookie.

```
var value = $.cookie('artname');
```

'artname' is the cookie name.

But it is displaying null because the cookie path is different. The path is `/v/abcfile/frontend/`.

But the path for the other cookies on the page i am trying to get is `/`.

I tried with this:

```
top.jQuery.cookie('artname');
```

But it's still showing me the same.

For path ii have tried with:

```
var value = $.cookie("artname", { path:'/v/vspfiles/frontend/' });
```

Its still showing me the null value.
How can I get value of cookie?

Answer (score 6):

When you save your cookies, set path to "/". Cookie will be available on all pages

```
$.cookie('artname', 'value', { path:'/'});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$.cookie.defaults = { path: '/' };
$.cookie("foo", "value" );
```